# Importing and analysing text data using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have created code in Python 2.7 which saves sales data for various products into a text file using the write() method. My limited Python skills have hit the wall with the next step - I need code which can read this data from the text file and then calculate and display the mean average number of sales of each item. The data is stored in the text file like the data shown below (but I am able to format it differently if that would help).

Product A,30

Product B,26

Product C,4

Product A,40

Product B,18

Product A,31

Product B,13

Product C,3

After far too long Googling around this to no avail, any pointers on the best way to manage this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you Google?  This is pretty straightforward.  If you want straight-up Python, you can use the csv module, but if you'll be working with data like this a lot, pandas is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can `read` from the file, then split each line by a space (`' '`). Then, it is just a matter of creating a dictionary, and appending each new item to a list which is the value for each letter key, then using `sum` and `len` to get the average.

### Example

```
products = {}
with open("myfile.txt") as product_info:
    data = product_info.read().split('\n') #Split by line
    for item in data:
        _temp = item.split(' ')[1].split(',')
        if _temp[0] not in products.keys():
            products[_temp[0]] = [_temp[1]]
        else:
            products[_temp[0]] = products[_temp[0]]+[_temp[1]]

product_list = [[item, float(sum(key))/len(key)] for item, key in d.items()]
product_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

for item in product_list:
    print 'The average of {} is {}'.format(item[0], item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
file1 = open("input.txt",'r') 
for line in file1:
    if len(line)>2:
        data = line.split(",")      
        a,b = data[0].strip(),data[1].strip()
        if a in dict1:      
           dict1[a] = dict1[a] + int(b)
        else:
           dict1[a] = int(b) 

            if a in dict2:      
           dict2[a] = dict2[a] + 1
        else:
           dict2[a] = 1  


for k,v in dict1.items():
   for m,n in dict2.items():
      if k == m:
          avg = float(v/n)       
          print "%s Average is: %0.6f"%(k,float(avg))
```

Output:

```
Product A Average is: 33.666667
Product B Average is: 19.000000
Product C Average is: 3.500000
```